# How do you output and indexed (black and white) tiff image in opencv

Tags: opencv, tiff, indexed-image

If I `imwrite` a binarized image, it only creates a grayscale image file not an indexed=2 file. What options do I need on the `imwrite` to accomplish this? I would also like LZW compression if possible.

```
  orig = cv2.imread('rgb.tiff')
  work = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  work = cv2.ximgproc.niBlackThreshold(work, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 41, -0.2,
    binarizationMethod=cv2.ximgproc.BINARIZATION_NICK)
  cv2.imwrite('bw.tiff', work)
```

[image: grayscale vs indexed]

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want a bi-level LZW-compressed TIFF, you can write one with **wand** like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image

# Open image and save as bi-level LZW-compressed version
with Image(filename='image.tif') as img: 
    img.compression='lzw'
    img.type='bilevel'
    img.save(filename='result.tif')
```

Input:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Note that you can save **OpenCV** images like this, but you must first convert from its BGR order to conventional RGB order first. You can use:

```
RGB = cv2.cvtColor(BGRimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

or pure Numpy:

```
RGB = BGRimage[...,::-1]
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, wand, TIFF, TIF, LZW, compressed, compression, bilevel, bi-level

Comment: I tried your wand code on this image but it came out grayscale.

[image.tif(zip)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pe42a3dhvb6e7aw/image.zip)

![result_info](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc3jk1y223efi79/result_info.png)

Comment: Oh, that's odd. I get a bi-level LZW-compressed result on my machine. Maybe you don't have `libtiff` installed, or your **ImageMagick** or `libtiff` are old versions...

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on windows 10 and installed the latest ImageMagick-7.0.10-14-Q16-x64-dll.exe before I filed an [issue](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/2069) with ImageMagick for performance problems with this bilevel problem. Now I'm running Q8. I'm able to do the conversion with this command: `magick mogrify -path ..\bw -colors 2 +dither -type bilevel -compress Group4 *.tiff` Any thoughts? Thanks. I also have the latest `wand` on Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

[imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite)
Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.